# How do I retrieve DataTables rows information with Shiny and DT?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I'm using Shiny and the DT package to display filtered tables from a MySQL database.

In short, I get an input value from the user, create an SQL query, capture the output and display it as a DataTable. The output can be further filtered using the DataTable column filters and the user should be able to download the filtered dataset.

According to the [DT docs](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html), `input$table_rows_all` should contain the row indices of the displayed table.
However when I press the download button, I get a file with only column names and no data.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(RMySQL)

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="myuser", host="myhost", dbname="mydb")

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 

                sqlOutput <- reactive({
                    sqlInput <- paste0("select * from mydb.mytable",
                           " where value < ", input$value,
                           ";")
                    dbGetQuery(con, sqlInput)
                })

                output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(sqlOutput(), server=TRUE, rownames=FALSE, filter="top", options=list(pageLength=10))

                output$download <- downloadHandler("filtered.data.txt", content = function(file) {
                                           rows <- input$table_rows_all
                                           write.table(sqlOutput()[rows, ], file, sep="\t", quote=FALSE, col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
                })

})
```

In the code above I save the output from `DBI::dbQuery()` into a reactive function `sqlOutput()` so that I can then pass it to both `DT::renderDataTable()` and `shiny::downloadHandler()`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure but it looks like `input$table_rows_all` is returning an empty vector for some reason.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your `downloadHandler` looks fine. Your `input$table_rows_all` returning an empty vector is probably the problem. You should probably edit your question and give your `ui.R` code so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't really reproducible but if you just want to be able to download the resulting table from shiny with `DT` I would look at the [DT extensions](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html).  There you can see that you can use `tableTools` to have an option to download instead of using the manual `downloadHandler`.

Here is a reproducible example demonstrating the functionality:

**Note** - you will need a `www` directory and `flash` installed in your browser.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data(iris)

runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel("DT Download Example"),
      mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
        )
      )
    ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      iris
    }, 
    extensions = 'TableTools',
    rownames=FALSE, 
    filter="top", 
    options=list(dom = 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                 tableTools = list(
                   sSwfPath = copySWF('www'),
                   aButtons = list('copy', 'print',
                                   list(
                                     sExtends = 'collection',
                                     sButtonText = 'Save',
                                     aButtons = c('csv','xls')
                                     )
                                   )
                   )
                 )
    )
  }))
```

Here is an untested version of the relevant part in your code:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  sqlOutput()
}, server=TRUE, 
extensions = 'TableTools',
rownames=FALSE, 
filter="top", 
options=list(pageLength=10,
             dom = 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
             tableTools = list(
               sSwfPath = copySWF('www'),
               aButtons = list('copy', 'print',
                               list(
                                 sExtends = 'collection',
                                 sButtonText = 'Save',
                                 aButtons = c('csv','xls'))))))
```

Comment: Down votes are far more useful when accompanied with a comment.